# Unable to run TypeScript and nodemon side by side

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm creating a RESTful API with Node.js, Express and TypeScript so I installed all the necessary dependencies including nodemon. In the TypeScript config file i made an alteration on line 58 where I changed `// "outDir":  "./"`  then  I uncommented it and change it to `"outDir": "./dist"` and I also combined the `nodemon` and `tsc -w` to work together using `"start" : "tsc -w & nodemon dist/app.js"` when I tried to run the code using `npm start` I discovered that it was only watching the changes but it wasn't running my server. what could be the problem?

I tried `"start": "tsc -w & nodemon dist/app.js`", in the `package.json` files then I ran `npm start` was expecting that the watch command and the server will start concurrently but the server didn't work only the watch command did.

Comment: Can you try with https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently library?

Comment: yes it worked with concurrently

Answer (score 1):

change you package.json to this

```
 "start": `"nodemon --watch *.ts --exec ts-node app.ts"`
```

this should work just change the directory to  what ever you want,
and I recommend this one

```
"start": "nodemon -L -e ts,json  --ext .ts --exec ts-node app.ts"
```

while using some environments like containers and please check github repo
https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting

Answer (score 0):

I have this working in one of my older projects by adding a `nodemonConfig` section to my `package.json`.

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon",
    },
    ...,
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
    },
    "nodemonConfig": {
        "exec": "npm run tsc",
        "ext": "js json ts",
        "watch": [
            "src",
            "node_modules",
            ".env"
        ]
    }
```

And then running `npm start`

Comment: Ok thanks but i later found a way of both typescript and nodemon using concurrently module